# Import and delete existing table in access

Tags: ms-access-2013

How to import a table from the backend file and replace the existing local table in the frontend file using autoexec macro, that is everytime the frontend is launched by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Create two queries. First query deletes all data in your local table. Second query appends all records from your backend table into the local table. Add these two queries into your autoexec macro.